# Makefile, recursive compiling and static libraries

Tags: c++, makefile

I got a project with the code in multiple directories, what I am trying to do is to recursively compile each of these directories, and this I can do.

I can create the static libraries so the `.a` files with this makefile

```
CXX=g++
CXXFLAGS=-std=c++11
PROJECT=admin.a

OBJECTS = Manager.o


all: $(PROJECT)

.cpp.o:
    @echo -e "\033[32m -Building "$*"...\033[0m"
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $<

$(PROJECT): $(OBJECTS)
    @echo -ne "\033[31m -Creating static library "$*"..."
    @(ar rcs $(PROJECT) $(OBJECTS))
    @echo -e "[DONE] \033[0m"

clean:
    @(rm -rf *.o)

mrproper: clean
    @(rm -rf $(EXEC))
```

But I don't know how to link these with my main program,

Any help will be very useful,

Thanks,

Comment: -1: Please show us what you've tried. It is very likely that the source "on the internet" already shows you how to do it, if you try.

Comment: I've added the code of the two type of makefile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include static libraries (`.a`) directly in your linker line:

```
gcc -o executable main.o admin.a
```